# Geometric locus of $M$ such that $|MA|^2 |MB|^2=a^2$

Tags: geometry

I want to find the geometric locus of point $M$ such that $|MA|^2 |MB|^2=a^2$ where $|AB|=2a$, Solving algebraic equation is not hard but I can't figure out the shape of this curve. Can anybody help?

Comment: no idea what any of your notation means.

Comment: If you're just looking for the shape: Take the points to be $A(-a,0)$ and $B(a,0)$, so that the equation is $((x+a)^2+y^2)((x-a)^2+y^2)=a^2$. Then, let WolframAlpha plot the thing. Here's $a=1$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%28%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%3D1 , and here's $a=2$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-2%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%28%28x%2B2%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%3D4, and $a=0.5$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-0.5%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%28%28x%2B0.5%29%5E2%2By%5E2%29%3D0.25

Comment: These curves are a special case of "Cassini Ovals": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toy with these shapes, you can try this:

1. Download and install [Cinderella](http://de.cinderella.de/) (free version should be enough)
2. Start it and add four free points ($A$ through $D$) to the construction
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a command input box
4. Check the “Permanent” checkbox next to that
5. Paste the following code:

   ```
   colorplot(if(dist(#,A)^2*dist(#,B)^2<(dist(A,B)/2)^2,[1,1,0],[0,0,1]),C,D,pxlres->1,startres->8);
   ```
6. Press enter

You should see a blue plot region, its shape determined by the points $C$ and $D$, and within this one or two yellow blobs, centered around $A$ and $B$ and delimited by the curve you asked about. Something like this:

[image: Cinderella Screenshot]

The code in detail:

```
colorplot(    // plot pixels depending on function value
  if(         // function is a case distinction
    dist(#,A)^2 * dist(#,B)^2 < (dist(A,B)/2)^2, // sign for your curve
    [1,1,0],  // yellow inside
    [0,0,1]   // blue outside
   ),
 C,D,         // these points control the plotting area
 pxlres->1,   // draw at finest resolution eventually
 startres->8  // draw at coarse resolution first for smooth movements
);
```

Also see the [CindyScript reference](http://doc.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php?page=CindyScript) [of the `colorplot` function](http://doc.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php?page=Function%20Plotting#colorplot).

Answer (score 0):

If points $A,B$ are fixed and negative distances are ruled out, the loci are quartic curves, *Ovals of Cassini.*  (Incorrectly ) he assumed them at first to be planetary orbit loci.

[Ovals_Cassini1](http://www.2dcurves.com/quartic/quarticca.html#Cassiniellipse)

[Ovals_Cassini2](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ovals%20of%20cassini&tbm=isch&imgil=rQTn4SpWRmIn0M%253A%253BIXGDtUv3ypcipM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fmathworld.wolfram.com%25252FCassiniOvals.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=rQTn4SpWRmIn0M%253A%252CIXGDtUv3ypcipM%252C_&usg=__YHm2tK1vFEGlIjL3ZKtH1_d1zsM%3D&biw=1082&bih=474&dpr=1.25&ved=0ahUKEwjR2v-MifbKAhWVC44KHTKPCo0QyjcIMA&ei=ENS_VtGSO5WXuASynqroCA#imgrc=rQTn4SpWRmIn0M%3A)

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoGebra's `LocusEquation` command [to create an implicit locus curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G239M.png). Then you can drag the free points and check how the curve is dynamically changing.